# Can't read data in OpenSSL C server

Tags: openssl

I ask for your help.
I am trying to receive data on the server side (OpenSSL in C language), the handshake stage goes well and there are no problems with this, but when I try to send data from the client, the server does not accept all the data, that is, the data comes in different sizes and cannot be completely received .
The server buffer size is 512,000 bytes.
Here is the server code that receives the data:
(server)

```
int do_server_read(SSL *ssl)
 {
     int err, nread;
     char buffer[512000];

         do
        {
         for (nread = 0; nread < sizeof(buffer); nread += err)
             {
             err = SSL_read(ssl, buffer + nread, sizeof(buffer) - nread);
             if (err <= 0)
                 break;
             }

         fwrite(buffer, 1, nread, stdout);
         }
         while (err > 0);

         return (SSL_get_shutdown(ssl) & SSL_RECEIVED_SHUTDOWN) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

(client):

```
int do_client_send(SSL *ssl)
{
    int err, nwritten;
    char buffer[512000];

    for (;;)
    {
        for (int a = 0; a < 512000; a++)
            buffer[a] = '\0';

        for (int i = 0; i < 261120; i++)
            buffer[i] = 'A';

        buf[strlen(buffer)] = 'W';

        for (nwritten = 0; nwritten < sizeof(buffer); nwritten += err)
        {
            err = SSL_write(ssl, buffer + nwritten, strlen(buffer) -    nwritten);
            if (err <= 0)
                return 0;
        }

    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to keep reading even when the SSL_read function returns 0? Sometimes you have to read multiple packets to get the data. Also, look for the SSL_read documentation, and you will find the correct way to check if you have to keep reading.

Comment: Thanks Lucas, the server accepts everything as expected, the error was on the client side, but I have a question:
Am I allocating memory correctly for the data received (by the server) char* buffer[5120000] or is there another correct way to allocate memory, taking into account the fact that there can be 200 connected clients in one second?